# Changing value in array of objects

Tags: c#, .net, reference, pass-by-reference, ref

I have a bit of code and I am confused with my observations

```
var arr = new Class[]
{
    new Class{Name = "First"},
    new Class{Name = "Second"}
};

var first = arr[0];

arr[0] = new Class { Name = "Third"};

Console.WriteLine(first.Name); //Name = First

class Class
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

At first , I thought that this code should write 'Third' because it is array of references to objects and we are changing arr[0] to 'Third' , but first variable has 'First' value after changing reference in the array.

I have assumption , that this happens because when we getting arr[0] we get reference by value , like if we pass object to some function we can change state of the object , but we can't change the entire object. That is why first variable continues to point on our object with name 'First'. I tried to prove this assumpition with this code

```
ref Class first = ref arr[0];

arr[0] = new Class { Name = "Third" };

Console.WriteLine(first.Name); //Name = Third
```

But i am not sure about it. Can someone proves or refutes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. The variable `first` is still pointing at the object that was originally located at `arr[0]`. Updating `arr[0]` will simply update that array element only, what `first` is referring to is unchanged.

Taking inspiration from Dan Abramov's excelling [Just Javascript](https://justjavascript.com/) series to explain variables and values, you can build a mental model of variables as "wires" that link variables to values. Your values here are `Class` object references. With this you can picture what's happening:

- You create an array of two elements. This creates two objects in memory to store something (two values, with wires back to each array element variable).
- You create the variable `first` which has a wire to `arr[0]`. `first` and `arr[0]` are now referring to the same value (object reference).
- You assign `arr[0]` to a new object. This creates a value (object reference) and moves the wire connecting `arr[0]` from the old value to that new one.
- The wire from `first` is untouched - it's still connected to the original value originally in `arr[0]`
  .

This mental model is for reference types, if your values are value types, then each use of `new` will create a new value and move the wire from the variable being assigned to that new value. There won't be any value with more than one wire connecting to it.